# How to print set list in object with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a class like this:

```
public class Subject extends Entitet{
   private String personalID;
   private String name;
   private Integer ECTS;
   private Profesor subjectBearer;
   private Set<Student> students;

//all getters and seters
```

In the main I have created a list that contains all the Subjects.

```
List<Subjet> subjets= new ArrayList<>();
```

And now I would like to print all Subjects name with all students that 
attend the classes.

I tried something like this but it gives me error :

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void

```
subjets.stream()
    .forEach(subj-> System.out.println(subj.getSubjectBearer().getName()+ " " + subj.getSubjectBearer().getLastName()+" "+
            subj.getStudents().stream()
                .forEach(stud->System.out.println(stud.getName()+" "+stud.getLastName()))
                 )
    );
```

I don't know how to make that this second stream returns string of `firstName` and `lastName` of every student. Can I  map it to string and then somehow collect it?
Something like this inside the first stream?

```
subj.getStudents().stream()
           .map(stud->(stud.getFirstName()+ stud.getLastName() )
           .collect(Collectors.toString())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `forEach` does not produce any results (returns void). So, your second `forEach` on students will not return anything while you expect something to be concatenated to the subject name.

You can either:

Return a string of all students

```
subjets.stream()
  .forEach(subj-> System.out.println(
      subj.getSubjectBearer().getName()+ " " + 
      subj.getSubjectBearer().getLastName()+" "+
      subj.getStudents().stream()
            .map(stud->stud.getName()+" "+stud.getLastName())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
  ));
```

Or print the name without concatenation:

```
subjets.stream()
    .forEach(subj-> {
       System.out.println(subj.getSubjectBearer().getName()+ " " + subj.getSubjectBearer().getLastName());
       subj.getStudents().stream()
           .forEach(stud->System.out.println(stud.getName()+" "+stud.getLastName()))
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The + operator error is occurring since you are using this:-

subj.getSubjectBearer().getLastName()+" **"+**
            subj.getStudents().stream().forEach(stud->System.out.println(stud.getName()+" "+stud.getLastName()))
                 )

The + operator is working on a String and void, because the second part which is creating a stream of students and then working on it is not returning any String.

Answer (score 0):

forEach method id is type of void. split your statement into two statements.

```
subjets.stream()
    .forEach(subj-> {System.out.println(subj.getSubjectBearer().getName()+ " " + subj.getSubjectBearer().getLastName());
            subj.getStudents().stream()
                .forEach(stud->System.out.println(stud.getName()+" "+stud.getLastName()))
                 )
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, try something like this:

```
subjets.stream()
    .forEach(subj-> System.out.println(subj.getSubjectBearer().getName() + " "
                    + subj.getSubjectBearer().getLastName() + " " + subj.getStudents()
                    .stream()
                    .map(stud -> stud.getName() + " " + stud.getLastName())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Comment: Can I ask a good soul to format the code for me. I am from the phone and I am unable to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you have some misspelling name in your attribute/method, but I guess it is not in your source code.

I think you should use System.out only once, and thus create the String presentation first, this way :

```
System.out.println(subjets.stream()
            .map(subj-> (subj.getName()+ " " + subj.getLastName() + " \n\t" +
                            subj.getStudents().stream().map(
                                    stud->stud.getFirstName() + " " + stud.getLastName()).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
                         )
            ).reduce("", String::concat)
        );
```

You can adapt separators as you want.

Let me know if you need further explanations.

Comment: Did you try this solution?

Answer (score 0):

subjets.stream()
        .forEach(subj->{
            System.out.println(subj.getSubjectBearer().getName()+ " " + subj.getSubjectBearer().getLastName());
            subj.getStudents().stream()
            .forEach(stud->System.out.println(stud.getName()+" "+stud).getLastName());

```
    });
```

I have Corrected your code .Please try and it should work

The reason for error is inside the System.out.println you are calling stream that cannot happen.SOP accept string object that needs to be seperated out.
Second thing for each accepts consumer  for multiple statements add curly braces and for each statement please end the statement by having ;

Answer (score 0):

may be of help :

```
listEntries.stream()
                .map(obj -> obj.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```